# How do I "Lock" the screen resolution w/GMA HD (i3-530 Dell 580s)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, windows-media-center

I have a Dell 580s with Win 7 x86 (yes 32 bit). Displaying on a Panisonic TH-37PX60U (720p). If I leave the computer running and power up the TV, frequently Media Center is displayed at about 25% of the screen area in a box centered in the display. I am not sure of the screen resolution but as soon as I minimize Media Center, the desktop returns to full resolution. I am then prompted with a Windows notification that my screen resolution is set to a resolution that is not ieal for my monitor.

Is there any way to "lock" the screen resolution at 1280 x 720 and not leave this up to Windows or the Intel driver? Not sure where the issue is. Either minimizing Media Center or sometimes turning the display off and then back on will resolve the issue but it happens about 80% of the time that I power up the display. I have played with the settings within Media Center and guessing that the issues originates with either the display or Intel driver / GMA.

The WAF (Wife Acceptance Factor) is suffering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give **[PowerStrip](http://download.cnet.com/PowerStrip/3000-2193_4-14972.html?tag=mncol)** a try, it ain't free but it works best for me when dealing with multiple displays and different resolutions.

Comment: Molly, At $30 and some doubt that this will really fix my issue, I am going to pass. For $25, I can get a dedicated graphics card that will do the job. I haven't had this issue with either ATI or nVidea cards. Gussing that this is something that will be fixed by Intel or has already been addressed (but I can't figure out how to set it.)

Comment: @Andrew Robinson - you're right, if your Dell has a PCIe slot, then your much better off with a decent graphics card, i wouldn't bother some crappy Intel GMA with HD video anyway :)

Comment: I generally agree that Intel has their work cut out for them but from a performance standpoint, their GMA HD (as part of an i3-530) is doing just fine. I have even boosted the desktop to 1080 and no issues. So if I could get the resolution locked down, I could save $25. Never game on this as it is a dedicated HTPC.

Comment: @Andrew Robinson - bah, some fanless ATI HD4350 with 1 GB RAM (around $25-30) is running circles around that GMA ... ideal for a HTPC.

Comment: @Molly, went with a nVidia 210. $25 from NE. Performance is fine and solved my changing resolution issue. 4.7 on the Win Experience index. The GMA HD was a 4.6 so if I can get the GMA to stick with a single resolution, I might remove the nVidia card. Guessing that will happen with the next Intel driver update. Oh well, maybe they can send me a check for $25.